# Using Groovy/Java to pass Read SOAP request through to Update SOAP request in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

Apologies if this has been answered in part elsewhere, but I have looked extensively (albeit I am new to using Soap UI/Ready API, so I am struggling to make sense of some of this...)

I am attempting to recreate a traditional "Update" record function in Soap UI. The steps as I see them are as follows:

1. Get a record through an SOAP API request step
2. Read the Response (in a Groovy script)
3. Create an object for the Update SOAP request
4. Pass all data from the Read through to the Update object (as yet unchanged)
5. Amend one or two items of data in the Update object
6. Call this object from a SOAP API request step

I believe I should be able to achieve this in 3 steps, with 2 through to 5 above in a single Groovy script.

I want to avoid Properties/Transfers as much as possible as these seem to be unable to pass the entire record between the Read and the Update steps, except one data item at a time. If I have multiple large records to be amended, this'll get out of control very quickly.

Ideally in time I would make this generic; the logic work dynamically, parsing the structure of the record that has been Read into the record to be Updated. But at this time I just want to know if the approach detailed above that I would like to implement is possible!

Comment: Are you looking for an answer other than "yes"? Please have a read through [help/on-topic] and perhaps [ask].

Comment: Let me clarify what my two biggest issues are. The messageExchange library is only available in an Assertion step, and I am having trouble accessing the message response (API Read) through other methods. Any advice on what calls I can make to access the SOAPMessage would be very welcome. Also, by what property would I be able to address the Update object if I created it in the Groovy script, assuming I still wanted to send it via the SOAP Update call?